# Cannot set value of property on checkbox binding

Tags: wpf

```
<CheckBox x:Uid="cbRFEnableManualControl" 
                      Grid.Column="0" 
                      Grid.Row="0" 
                      Name="cbRFEnableManualControl" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="0,0,0,12"
                      IsChecked="{Binding RFEnableManualControl, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Checked="RFEnableManualControlChanged"
                      Unchecked="RFEnableManualControlChanged">
                <CheckBox.Content x:Uid="EnableManualControlContent">
                    Enable manual control
                </CheckBox.Content>
            </CheckBox>
```

If I check this checkbox then i should enable some controls. I have a property "RFEnableManualControl" in my data model class, based on this value am enabling/disabling the other controls.

Issue is, i have another one button, if i check this checkbox after clicking this button the value is not set for this property. the execution is not going into this property and directly hitting the RFEnableManualControlChanged event.
In this another one button am calling the constructor of this data model class but am not assiging anything to this particular property.

Comment: Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on property RFEnableManualControl and in a class that contains this property?

Comment: yes, implemented this INotifyPropertyChanged already. issue is, execution flow is not going to this datamodel class.

Comment: Check your bindings. Check the output of the `Output` panel in VS. Make sure to have binding errors output to the output panel in the options.

Comment: Your problem is *not* reproducible from your code example and therefore could be caused by many different things. Please edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).